# Access to the extension created with civix via url

Tags: extension, civix

Hi Everyone i've create  an extension with civix and i've generated page.Now i want to access to this page a've created. Anybody know how to deal with this or have an exemple of url. My extension is well activated . Tnks

Comment: Can you edit the question to show what's in the xml/menu folder? There should be a file in there that has a url inside.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<menu>
  <item>
    <path>civicrm/modify-particpant</path>
    <page_callback>CRM_Modifyparticpantrole_Page_ModifyParticipant</page_callback>
    <title>ModifyParticipant</title>
    <access_arguments>access CiviCRM</access_arguments>
  </item>
</menu>   THis is the content of xml file in menu folder

Comment: when i add civicrm/modify-particpant to the url it redirect me to the civicrm dashboard.

Comment: There's a typo in the class name but if the actual classname also has it then as long as it matches it should be ok. Try /civicrm/menu/rebuild?reset=1 first.

Comment: big problem doing /civicrm/menu/rebuild?reset=1 first. My site broke and now i cannot access to any administrator page with error ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.please help

Comment: Move the xml file and try menu rebuild again.

Comment: i've deleted the whole module and the problem is still here. i can do anything now what is happed.is civicrm enought stable on linux and drupal ?

Comment: There's probably a config item that was wrong somewhere before and now the rebuild has picked it up. Is it drupal 7? You can try in mysql `update system set status=0 where name like '%civicrm%';` to disable civi.

Comment: i've deleted the database and imported the backup. Now i'm back from previous problem and afraid to rebuild the menu again. i can access to civi page now. Yes drupal 7, civicrm 5.6 and linux distribution.